# Symfony doctrine returns objects instead of arrays

Tags: arrays, symfony, object, doctrine-orm

I have no idea why, but after a few (unrelated) changes all my returns are objects instead of arrays. For example:

ReceiptController.php

```
/**
 * Get all receipts for the team.
 *
 * @param String $id
 * @return array
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=201,
 *     description="Get all receipt for the team.",
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *         type="array"
 *     )
 * )
 */
public function getTeamReceiptsAction($id): array
{
    $parameterBag = [
        'teamId' => $id
    ];

    $items = $this->manager->getAll($parameterBag);

    return $items;
}
```

Receiptrepository

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getFilterQuery($parameterBag): QueryBuilder
{
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ;

    if (isset($parameterBag['id'])) {
        $qb->andWhere('s.id=(:id)')
            ->setParameter('id', $parameterBag['id']);
    }

    if (isset($parameterBag['teamId'])) {
        $qb->andWhere('s.team=(:team)')
            ->setParameter('team', $parameterBag['teamId']);
    }

    return $qb;
}


/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAll($parameterBag): ?array
{
    $qb = $this->getFilterQuery($parameterBag);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Returns: 
`{"0":{"email":"admin@benj.be","first_name"...`
While i would expect `[{"email":"admin@benj.be","first_name"...` ?

So it returns an object with multiple objects in it instead of an array.

But that's weird, because all my functions are typed to return array's, and I don't get any errors?

Comment: Do a dump(get_class($items)) and see what kind of object it is. Could be an object that implements the various array interfaces which in turn will pass the array type tests.

Comment: If I do that, I get the following Internal Error: `{"code":500,"message":"Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given"}`.

Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change this:

```
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

to this:

```
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

In this mode you can retrieve results in array

Or as Tomasz Madeysk wrote try this:

```
return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult()
```

Comment: or another way to accomplish that: `getQuery()->getArrayResult()` (it's the same under the hood)

Comment: yes, I prefer Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY but is another good solution!